# Django - Insert data into child table once the parent record is created

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using `Django REST Framework` and facing a problem during inserting data into the child table. There are 2 models named `Card` and `ContactName` that have the following fields. The `Card` has a relation with `ContactName` via a foreign key field name `card`.

`models.py`:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename

class ContactName(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    confidence = models.FloatField(default=0)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contact_name')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

`serializers.py` file:

```
class ContactNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactName
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'confidence', 'card', 'created_at', 'updated_at']


class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact_name = ContactNameSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ['id', 'image', 'filename', 'contact_name', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

In `ViewSet` once the card record is created, I also want to add the following `ContactName` `JSON` data into the child table, set the reference *(card_id)* as an id of that card, and return the newly added record in the response.

`e.g.`

```
[
  {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "confidence": 0.9
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Doe",
    "last_name": "John",
    "confidence": 0.5
  }
]
```

`views.py`:

```
class CardViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CardSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        cards_serializer = CardSerializer(data=request.data)
        if cards_serializer.is_valid():
            cards_serializer.save()

            # insert the record into the child table and set the reference (card_id) as an id
            json = [
                {
                    "first_name": "John",
                    "last_name": "Doe",
                    "confidence": 0.9
                },
                {
                    "first_name": "Doe",
                    "last_name": "John",
                    "confidence": 0.5
                }
            ]

            return Response(cards_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(cards_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I really appreciate the help. The final response will be something like this:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "image": "/media/abc.jpg",
  "filename": "abc.jpg",
  "contact_names": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "confidence": 0.9,
      "card_id": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Doe",
      "last_name": "John",
      "confidence": 0.5,
      "card_id": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can pass this data to your `serializer` by [`Including extra context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) and by overriding the `create` method as you are doing in your code:

views.py

```py
class CardViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CardSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        json = [
            {
                "first_name": "John",
                "last_name": "Doe",
                "confidence": 0.9
            },
            {
                "first_name": "Doe",
                "last_name": "John",
                "confidence": 0.5
            }
        ]
        
        serializer = CardSerializer(data=request.data, context={'contacts': json})
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Also, override the `create` method on `CardSerializer`, to first create the instance  using the validated data and then use the `extra context data` to create `ContactName` objects and assign them to the new `Card` instance:

serializers.py

```py
class ContactNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ContactName
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'confidence', 'card']


class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact_name = ContactNameSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Card
        fields = ['id', 'image', 'filename', 'contact_name', 'created_at', 'updated_at']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = models.Card.objects.create(**validated_data)
        contacts = self.context.get('contacts', None)
        for contact in contacts:
            models.ContactName.objects.create(**contact, card=instance)
            
        return instance
```

#### A few notes:

If you want `card_id` instead of `card` on the response data then change your field name (and update the serializer fields):

```py
class ContactName(models.Model):
    ...
    card_id = models.ForeignKey(Card...)
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can just override [`.to_representation`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields), remove the `key:pair` and reinsert with the new key value.

Also, I would change this relationship to a many-to-many in order to avoid `ContactName` duplicates in your database.